# Debugging Externally Launched Code in Wing IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, remote-debugging, wing-ide

I've been trying to find a solution for this but no luck so far. I'm trying to debug an externally launched code in WingIDE with the following code:

```
import wingdbstub
wingdbstub.Ensure()
```

And I received an exception during the debug:

```
ValueError: No debugger
```

Hovering on the red colour bug reads the following:

```
Program exception; pid=19080; Listening on TCP/IP port 50005
Allowed hosts: 127.0.0.1 [0 modules loaded]
```

This is the [wingdbstub.py](https://pastebin.com/nEMJ2Hv2) for reference.

I looked up for workarounds and they were referring to the kLogFile? I wasn't sure what to change in there. (Does it accept filepath? What should I change in there?)

If anyone can help me understand what's going on and suggest a fix to get rid of the exception, I'd be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try setting kLogFile in wingdbstub.py to the full path to a log file.  The log file is created if not already existing.  For example:

kLogFile="/Users/Me/debug.log"

The path of course needs to change depending on what OS you're on, etc.  You can email the resulting file to support@wingware.com to get help if you want...

Comment: I have modified it with kLogFile = "D:\user\Documents\python\debug.log" but it doesn't output any log file during the debug, can you help me on that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the followup until now when another user referenced this question.  You have to either double up the backslashes or use a raw string like kLogFile = r"D:\user\Documents\python\debug.log"